# Get data in arabic language, or get in english if it doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, localization

How are you all?

I'm sorry for my English.

I have two tables

**menus** and **menus_localization**

### Menu Table

```
| id_menu | section_menu | active_menu |
|    1    |    footer    |     yes     |
|    2    |    footer    |     yes     |
```

### Localization Table

```
| id_localization | id_menu |   name_menu   | link_menu                   | language_menu |
|       1         |    1    |      Home     |  http://example.com         |    english    |
|       2         |    1    |الصفحة الرئيسية|  http://example.com         |     arabic    |
|       3         |    2    |     signup    |  http://example.com/signup  |     english   |
```

Now, I want to get a menus in Arabic language, and if it doesn't exist get it in English.

Like This:

```
الصفحة الرئيسية
Signup
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`menus_localization` ML)
JOIN `menus` MS ON `MS`.`id_menu` = `ML`.`id_menu`
WHERE `MS`.`section_menu` =  'footer'
AND `ML`.`language_menu` =  'Arabic'
OR `ML`.`language_menu` =  'English'
GROUP BY `ML`.`id_menu`
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: thanks , but if you can change my query , I can't do it plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you need to join `menus` with `menus_localization` twice using id and language. Then use `COALESCE()` or `IFNULL()` to take `menu_name` in arabic first if it's not null, otherwise fallback for english.

```
SELECT m.id_menu, 
       m.section_menu, 
       m.active_menu,
       COALESCE(l2.name_menu, l1.name_menu) name_menu,
       COALESCE(l2.link_menu, l1.link_menu) link_menu
FROM menus m LEFT JOIN 
     menus_localization l1 ON m.id_menu = l1.id_menu AND 
                              l1.`language_menu` =  'english' LEFT JOIN
     menus_localization l2 ON m.id_menu = l2.id_menu AND 
                              l2.`language_menu` =  'arabic'
```

**[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93781/1)**

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using php from the tags you added. if so, do a query that retrieve the information of your page.
something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM your_table  WHERE id_menu ='1'
```

with this query you will get two results :

```
|       1         |    1    |      Home     |  http://example.com         |    english    |
|       2         |    1    |الصفحة الرئيسية|  http://example.com         |     arabic    |
```

you can an if statment to determine the language that you want to display

```
if($arabic) { // display arabic } else { // display english}
```